# ONSEN slider : relative links within pages accessed via slider menu

Tags: javascript, html, onsen-ui

Onsen ui Slider works fine for calling simple pages.
I managed to have somthing like so working:

```
<ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item"
 ng-click="menu.setMainPage('dir_02/index.html', {closeMenu: true})">
```

However the links to sub directories called from within dir_02/index.html will not work.
For example the line below is part of the html of dir_02/index.html:

```
link href="../cssdir/css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
```

The links in themselves are fine. They work if I launch my minisite directly from dir_02/index.html manually.

As an aside, I also realized that f I put all the html files that dir_02/index.html can manually lead to via hyperlinks, at the root level (www), the manual hyperlinks work (if I click on them I get the intended page). BUT the slider disappears!

However if I leave the files where they are supposed to be (that is, within the "dir02" folder, the link does no work. This is suprising since the link is written like so:

```
    href "someotherpage.html"
```

It should be looking within the same directory , shouldn't it?

But if I open it via the slider, the browser cannot find the file(s).

Is there a workaround?

Thanks, this is crucial to my project!
:-)

Comment: I got around the CSS part: changing the links to /path rather than ../path was the way to go. Besides the inline html ref to icones (scr) have to be without a slash so dir/image.png rather than ../dir/image.png.
That is good but I still lose the slider when accessing to another page via a hyperlink located on the page.

Comment: On top of that I realized that javascript does not work (eventhough embeded in the page called by slider) I am wondering if Onsenui is the way to go...